# Send a notification to a specific email address every time a data extension has updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, event, triggered-send

We have a form web associated with a triggered email send. When a person complete that form, it populates into a data extension (let's call it "A") and received an email that says that very soon someone will contact him/her.

**We need to send a notification email to our team, every time a record is inserted into this "A" data extension, so they can check the case and call the person. The team doesn't have an user on SFMC, so this email address in generic like "contact@help.com".**

I was searching about fire events in journey builder but I'm not getting with the solution.

Can someone help me out with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Triggers - Easiest solution would be to trigger two emails a) the initial form completion and b) the one to the internal staff.
2. Journey Builder - Essentially the same solution as JB is built on triggers. Send the subscriber through a journey, in the canvas have an update contact activity and write a new record two a second DE that triggers another journey. Or just fire an event for each journey...but #1 would make more sense.
3. CC Functionality - Send a carbon copy of the email, this is a paid feature...probably not worth it.
4. SF Connector - If you have the connector installed and are using SalesCloud for case management you could run them through a journey and have the journey update the the details in SalesCloud automatically.